# Unix sorting multiple conditions

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, unix

I have a file in which there are numbers like

```
6.3.0.00.220
6.3.0.00.220C
6.3.0.00.220EH
6.3.0.00.221
6.3.0.00.221C
6.3.0.00.221EH
```

and so on

I want them to be groped/sorted as

```
6.3.0.00.220EH
6.3.0.00.221EH
6.3.0.00.220C
6.3.0.00.221C
6.3.0.00.220
6.3.0.00.221
```

Basically EH ones together in ascending then C together in ascending and then the rest in ascending.

I am trying `sort -k 1.10,1.14 -nr | sort -k 1.13 -r` but not getting the exact output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this work for you 
`sort -r -t. -k5.4 -s somefile.txt`

Comment: Avoid [Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)

Answer (score 1):

Test file:

```
$ cat test.txt 
6.3.0.00.220
6.3.0.00.220C
6.3.0.00.220EH
6.3.0.00.221
6.3.0.00.221C
6.3.0.00.221EH
```

Running a command:

```
$ cat <(grep -E -e "EH$" test.txt | sort) \
      <(grep -E -e "C$" test.txt | sort) \
      <(grep -E -v "(EH)|(C)$" test.txt | sort)
6.3.0.00.220EH
6.3.0.00.221EH
6.3.0.00.220C
6.3.0.00.221C
6.3.0.00.220
6.3.0.00.221
```

Comment: Look, I have updated my answer to show that is works.

Comment: I guess I am doing something wrong not working for me can we do it through sort command,

Comment: I have found an error. I forgot to sort each grep command's output. However, it migth be useful if you mention what doesn't work.

Comment: It removes the EH numbers and gives me the leftovers in the file.